# How to fix encoding issue in a python script for spanish alphabet

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

This short script is to convert a CSV into a JSON. The CSV contains letters in spanish alphabet, which is still UTF-8 I believe. The script seems to have issue reading letters like ñ or é from the CSV.

After executing

```
python2 csvToJSON.py
```

This console returns 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 11: invalid continuation byte'

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs

import csv
import json
csvfile = codecs.open('practice.csv', encoding='utf-8').read()
# csvfile = open('practice.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("contraseña", "id")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: It seems to be in one of the ISO-8859-x encodings not in UTF-8.

Comment: The Python 2 `csv` module used to have problems with UTF-8, not sure if they were ever fixed. Is there a good reason you're not using Python 3 which is the recommended and supported version of the language?

Comment: I see various problems with your code. For one, the `csv` library expects an open file (file handle), not a string. Also, the value of `csvfile` is of type `unicode`, which the `csv` library can't handle in Python 2; it operates on `str` only. Furthermore, the string `"contraseña"` should be `u"contraseña"`. And it's unclear which line causes the decode error; please show the full traceback.

Comment: And, as tripleee said, if you can, switch to Python 3. It will make your life much easier with respect to encodings.

Comment: @lenz The full traceback at the terminal is:         
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvToJSON.py", line 12, in <module>
    for row in reader:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 112, in __next__
    row = next(self.reader)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 11: invalid continuation byte` The same error is produced with Python3

Comment: Here are the split files I'd like to convert before importing into MongoDB. [source files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cd0n9ip6sqxs9m2/delitosEnCDMX.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Did you ever try Klaus D.'s suggestion? My guess is that the data are encoded with ISO-8859-1, ie. use `encoding='latin-1'` in line 6.